# d3js attach object to svg

Tags: javascript, object, svg, d3.js

I am creating a very long div containing hundreds of svg lines created by the following method:

```
function visualizeit(ORFdata,max) {
    var browser = d3.select("#viewer")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", max/10)
        .attr("height",'50%');

    //Add svg to the svg container
    for (orf in ORFdata) {
        var line = browser.append("svg:line");
            var object = ORFdata[orf]
            line.datum(object)
            line.attr("id", 'mygroup'+orf)
            line.attr("x1", function(d){ return ORFdata[orf]["start"]/10})
            line.attr("x2", function(d){ return ORFdata[orf]["stop"]/10})
            line.attr("y1", function(d){ if (ORFdata[orf]["strand"] == "+1") {return 50} else {return 10}})
            line.attr("y2", function(d){ if (ORFdata[orf]["strand"] == "+1") {return 50} else {return 10}})
            line.style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
            line.style("stroke-width", orf)
            line.on('mouseover', function(d){console.log(d3.select("#mygroup"+orf).datum())})
        }
}
```

However, when I do a mouseover on no matter what line I only get the data back from the last element. At first I thought it was due to 'mygroup' so I added a counter to it +orf but it somehow still erases my older stored data.

When I look in the created html code a svg seems correct by ID at least.

`<line id="mygroup50" x1="103356.7" x2="103231.1" y1="10" y2="10" style="stroke: #06789b;  stroke-width: 50px;"></line>`

But somewhere the link goes awfully wrong...

How I fixed it so far...

```
        var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                           .attr("width", max/10)
                           .attr("height", '50%');

    //Add svg to the svg container
    var lines = svgContainer.selectAll("line")
        .data(ORFdata)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", function(d){ return d.start/10})
        .attr("y1", function(d){ if (d.strand == "+1") {return 65} else {return 10}})
        .attr("x2", function(d){ return d.stop/10})
        .attr("y2", function(d){ if (d.strand == "+1") {return 65} else {return 10}})
        .attr("stroke-width","25")
        .attr("stroke",function(d) {if (d.strand == "+1") {return 'green'} else {return 'red'}})
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {console.log(d.start)})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a bunch of closures in a loop.  Each of the functions you create have the variable `orf` in their closure scope but your loop is changing the value of `orf`.  By the time the function runs when the mouse over event fires, `orf` has its final value so therefore your `#mygroup + orf` selection will always pick up the last element.

Here's a good page on closures that has a section detailing the pitfalls of closures in a loop: http://conceptf1.blogspot.ca/2013/11/javascript-closures.html.

In D3 you can get around this problem by using data joins instead of an external loop.  Here's a good tutorial that should help to understand how this works:
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Answer (score 1):

You need to create different event handlers for each line object, what I mean is store those line ojects them in an associated array or something. This way you are probably overwriting each time.

If you could provide a jsfiddle or something I would be happy to test this theory out for you...